# FactoryGirl override attribute of associated object

Tags: ruby, rspec, associations, factory-bot

This is probably silly simple but I can't find an example anywhere.

I have two factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    user

    title "director"
    bio "I am very good at things"
    linked_in "http://my.linkedin.profile.com"
    website "www.mysite.com"
    city "London"
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do |u|
    u.first_name {Faker::Name.first_name}
    u.last_name {Faker::Name.last_name}

    company 'National Stock Exchange'
    u.email {Faker::Internet.email}
  end
end
```

What I want to do is override some of the user attributes when I create a profile:

```
p = FactoryGirl.create(:profile, user: {email: "test@test.com"})
```

or something similar, but I can't get the syntax right. Error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: User(#70239688060520) expected, got Hash(#70239631338900)
```

I know I can do this by creating the user first and then associating it with the profile, but I thought there must be a better way.

Or this will work:

```
p = FactoryGirl.create(:profile, user: FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "test@test.com"))
```

but this seems overly complex. Is there not a simpler way to override an associated attribute?
What is the correct syntax for this??

Answer (score 25):

According to one of FactoryGirl's creators, you can't pass dynamic arguments to the association helper ([Pass parameter in setting attribute on association in FactoryGirl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434572/pass-parameter-in-setting-attribute-on-association-in-factorygirl)).

However, you should be able to do something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    transient do
      user_args nil
    end
    user { build(:user, user_args) }

    after(:create) do |profile|
      profile.user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can call it almost like you wanted:

```
p = FactoryGirl.create(:profile, user_args: {email: "test@test.com"})
```

Comment: Great answer. Would you update this to comply with the latest Rails versions. Eg. I'm getting a "DEPRECATION WARNING: `#ignore` is deprecated and will be removed in 5.0." when implementing this answer.

Comment: You can use "transient" instead of "ignore" to get rid of the warning

Answer (score 6):

I think you can make this work with callbacks and transient attributes.  If you modify your profile factory like so:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    user

    ignore do
      user_email nil  # by default, we'll use the value from the user factory
    end

    title "director"
    bio "I am very good at things"
    linked_in "http://my.linkedin.profile.com"
    website "www.mysite.com"
    city "London"

    after(:create) do |profile, evaluator|
      # update the user email if we specified a value in the invocation
      profile.user.email = evaluator.user_email unless evaluator.user_email.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

then you should be able to invoke it like this and get the desired result:

```
p = FactoryGirl.create(:profile, user_email: "test@test.com")
```

I haven't tested it, though.

Comment: Thanks, but I would want that to work for any attribute, so I wouldn't want to have to code it for each like that. Maybe nobody else needs this...

Comment: I think your example has an error.  Change the `after(:create)` to be `profile.user.email = evaluator.user_email unless evaluator.user_email.nil?`

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by creating User first, and then Profile:

```
my_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, user_email: "test@test.com")
my_profile = FactoryGirl.create(:profile, user: my_user.id)
```

So, this is almost the same as in the question, split across two lines.
Only real difference is the explicit access to ".id".
Tested with Rails 5.